# JPA Basic types cascading

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have a very big object, with several hundreds of members, and some basic type attributes (`Integer`, `String` etc.)

Whenever `save()`ing one of these basic types, a heavy `Cascade` operation for all members occur.

e.g:

```
@Entity
public class Account {

private String someAttribute;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true) @ForceSerialize @GUI(changedBy={AccountType.ALL}) @SpecialEdit
public List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();

}
```

Say I have an `Account` with 1000 groups, each of 10 attributes,
Whenever I modify the `someAttribute` String, a huge cascade operation occurs.

I there a way to avoid it, when editing one specific `String` attribute, other than wrapping it in another Object?

Comment: Thanks @DN1, editted accordingly. are you sure basic types don't trigger a cascade persist?

Comment: I think I wasn't clear with my Question. I'll edit it again. Thanks

Comment: Have you found out whether you need to do cascades on specific actions? You might want to adjust your cascade type to something more appropriate, or try to remove the cascading entirely if this doesn't cause any compatibility issues (is the database and such designed in such a way that this would be an issue? If so, you might want to consider a redesign and migration)

Comment: in JPA Set<Group> is preferred over List<>